# How can i get Google click id (gclid) in my android app?

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, google-ads-api, adsense

I have an advertisment in google adsense for my android application and i know that when user clicks on ads, google create the link with info about user for tracking. So i want to get that link and gclid parameter inside it. How can i do that?

I already tried to do it with intent and google play install referrer, but intent returns null, and google play install referrer returns empty string or sometimes FEATURE_NOT_SUPPORTED

This is my intent getting code:

```
        val intent = this.intent
        val uri = intent?.data
        urlFromIntent = uri.toString()
```

Manifest:

```
       <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver"
                  android:enabled="true"
                  android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService"
                 android:enabled="true"
                 android:exported="false" />
```

And my google play install referrer code:

```
        mRefferClient = InstallReferrerClient.newBuilder(this).build()
        mRefferClient.startConnection(object : InstallReferrerStateListener {

            @SuppressLint("SwitchIntDef")
            override fun onInstallReferrerSetupFinished(responseCode: Int) {
                when (responseCode) {
                    InstallReferrerClient.InstallReferrerResponse.OK -> {
                        try {
                            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Log.d("InstallReferrerState", "OK")
                            var response = mRefferClient.installReferrer
                            urlFromReferClient = response.installReferrer
                            urlFromReferClient += ";" + response.referrerClickTimestampSeconds
                            urlFromReferClient += ";" + response.installBeginTimestampSeconds
                            mRefferClient.endConnection()
                        } catch (e: RemoteException) {
                            urlFromReferClient = e.toString()
                        }
                    }
                    InstallReferrerClient.InstallReferrerResponse.FEATURE_NOT_SUPPORTED -> {
                        urlFromReferClient = "FEATURE_NOT_SUPPORTED"
                }
                    InstallReferrerClient.InstallReferrerResponse.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE -> {
                        urlFromReferClient = "SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE"
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onInstallReferrerServiceDisconnected() {
                // Try to restart the connection on the next request to
                // Google Play by calling the startConnection() method.
            }
        })
```

Comment: have you found any solution?